# Passing a numpy bool array to a C++ class template via SWIG

Tags: python, swig

I'm trying to use SWIG to pass a numpy bool array to a C++ class template whose constructor has the standard %apply statement.

In python:

```
x = numpy.array( [True,False,True], dtype='bool' )
```

In *.i file:

```
%apply(bool* INPLACE_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(bool* atValueIn, int iDim1In)}
```

In C++ class template (constructor):

```
Data<bool,1>( bool* x, int size ); // Should be resolved by compiler to this
```

I get errors telling me that it can't find the correct constructor.  The list of possible constructors listed by the error message includes the one I show above.  I tried `dtype='bool8'` and `dtype='bool_'` in python with no success.  I also tried using unsigned char at the C++ level with no success.

Note that this code works for other data types like int32 (int), float32 (float), etc.

Note that I have another case where I pass a non-numpy bool to a another C++ template constructor whose argument is a boolean scalar and that works fine.

Any help?